# Older Powershell version command like Get-NetFirewallRules

Tags: powershell, firewall

I want to know if there is a cmdlet like `Get-NetFirewallRules` because i need to get my firewall rules, but in my server it run a older version of powershell.
I need to get info like local port, local address and remote address.

Here's my powershell version:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: You should include the version of powershell you're running in the question

Comment: i've modified my question: